# How do I add jQuery 'tinycarousel' plugin in Rails app

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, plugins, jquery-plugins

I have to use jQuery plugin 'tinycarousel' in my Rails app.

I have added the plugin in

```
vendor/assets/javascripts
```

I also added in application.js

```
//= require jquery.tinycarousel.min
```

In my html file i did:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
          $(document).ready(function(){
              $('.contract-notification').tinycarousel();
          });
 </script>
```

When I execute this in my browser I got error which tells

```
 Undefined is not a function.
```

i.e. It cannot recognize .tinycarousel()

What am I doing wrong?

Also when I check my Resources in browser I could not find tinycarousel plugin. It is not loaded. What should I do to load this plugin also?

Comment: Undefined is not a function is exactly because your plugin file don't load: you should make the plugin load first.
Check your file in vendor/assets/javascripts named exactly as "jquery.tinycarousel.min.js" and sits in the root of the folder

Comment: Ya I have named it correctly and placed it in vendors/assets/javascripts. What do you mean by 'sits in the root of the folder'?

Comment: I mean that it there are not any containing the file folders.
Hmm... very strange. I hope you wrote up there "vendors" as mistype.

Try to add manually the folder then: in config/application.rb
config.assets.paths << Rails.root.join('vendor', 'assets', 'javascripts')

Comment: @Suganya check the network tab to see if the resource is loaded properly. else open your console and type `$.fn.tinycarousel` and give enter, this should give the function definition if its defined. also make sure you include jQuery library BEFORE loading this file

Comment: also, try using an id instead of class as selector

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to all your valuable comments.

I just added

```
  <script type="text/javascript" **src="/assets/jquery.tinycarousel.min.js"**>
          $(document).ready(function(){
              $('.contract-para').tinycarousel();
              $('.contract-notification-close').click(function(){
                  $('.contract-notification').hide();
              });

          });
      </script>
```

and I got it working.